# How to determine relative position with only base angles known?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to make automated lawn mower based on Arduino , but I got stuck in mathematics part.

Here comes the question:

[image]

I need to determine relative position of the lawn mower "circle" in the (% of X, % of Y),when only angles (ab,bc,cd,da) are known (measured by lawn mower).

Answer or direction to helpful resource would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need some information about the rectangle $ABCD$ as well, E.g. if you know the coordinates of three corners and the angles of the lines originating from those corners this should be enough.

Comment: Yes, circle represents lawn mower and it measures angles between points (A,B,C,D). Coordinates will be % of (X,Y) since we do not know how big lawn is.

Comment: This will not suffice. You can place the corners individually on any point of their line and you will get the same angles, but totally different relative coordinates.

Comment: You might add some initial run, where your mower discovers the geometry by driving to three of the corners.

Comment: @mvw I am assuming the lawn is a rectangle.

Comment: You could draw many rectangles, all which yield the same angles. That will not be enough. There is a reason real world triangulation involves measuring distance from the beacons.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel  Yes,lawn is rectangle, in the image represented as "blue square"

Comment: This problem seems so easy.

Comment: This problem seems so easy: if opposite  angels  are same you are on 50% of X and 50% of Y "center of lawn". Or if angle (ab) is 180 deg. you know that you are on  0% of X "line AB",and so on.  But I can't put it to formula to calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the figure below:
[image]

It suffices to work with 2 angles: $\alpha$:=angle cd (in green) and $\beta$:=angle da (in red). The other angle information is redundant.

Let us recall the property of inscribed angle: the set of points from which one "sees" a fixed segment under a given angle is an arc of circle (and this segment is then a chord of this circle). The two arcs corresponding to the two angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the two chords $DC$ and $DA$ are drawn on the figure above.

We assume the coordinates $(c,0)$ of $C$ and $(0,a)$ of $A$ as known.

How can we deduce the coordinates $(x_E,y_E)$ of $E$ from the knowledge of angles $\alpha$ and $beta$ ? This will result of rather simple formulas that we are going to establish in three steps:

- step 1: find the coordinates of intersection points $I(x_I=c,y_I)$ and $H(x_H,y_H=a)$ with line $BC$ and line $AB$ resp. (warning: these points may be situated outside line *segments* $BC$ or $AB$): 
  $$y_I=\dfrac{c}{\tan(\alpha)} \ \ \text{and} \ \ x_H=\dfrac{a}{\tan(\beta)}.$$
- step 2: compute the equations of circles with resp. diameters $DI$ and $DH:$

$$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2-x_Ix-y_Iy&=&0& \ \ (a)\\x^2+y^2-x_Hx-y_Hy&=&0& \ \ (b)\end{cases}$$

- step 3: solve this system. This is quite easy, because, by substraction we obtain a first degree relationship which is in fact the equation of straight line $DE$:

$$y=k x \ \ \text{with} \ \ k=- \dfrac{x_I-x_H}{y_I-y_H} \ \ \ (c)$$

Plugging this expression into (a), we obtain the abscissa of $E$: $x=\dfrac{x_I +k y_I}{1+k^2} $ (eliminating spurious solution $x=0$ that corresponds to point $D).$

Remark: $E$ is on line $IH$. Explanation: $HD$ and $DI$ are diameters of their resp. arcs, thus $\widehat{HED}=\widehat{IED}=\pi/2$.

Here is a short Matlab program using the different formulas above for the computation of the coordinates of $E:$

> deg=pi/180; % conversion factor degrees -> radians
>   a=2;c=3; % width and length
>   alpha=76.15$*$deg;beta=43.47$*$deg; % angles input
>   xH=a/tan(beta);yH=a;
>   xI=c;yI=c/tan(alpha);
>   k=-(xI-xH)/(yI-yH); % slope of DE
>   x=(xI +k$*$yI)/(1+k^2);y=k$*$x; % coord. of E
>   x,y

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!    My math knowledge  isn't good,so  I am not sure how to use Your answer to solve my problem.   I will try to figure it out in next couple of days.   Thank You one more time!

Comment: @JenaMarie  I have transferred Your Matlab program to Ms Excel sheet and used SketchUP to test results ,and it works great ! Even over 100% (X,Y)!  Again, thank You very very much!!!

Comment: A happy end ! I think that the essential trick here is the use of these points $H$ and $I$ yielding a very simple computation (i didn't find this at once...)